# Azure Event Hub periodically generate 508 B message to Data Storages

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

When I Capturing Azure Event Hub to any Data Storage (Azure Blob Storage or Azure Data Lake) it's starts too send 508 B header of message (empty message) every 5 minute.

How can I solve this problem? because we want to use this mechanism for logging system, and it will interfere us.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely aware, but Event Hubs Capture now offers the option to turn off the sending of these empty files.

When configuring Event Hubs Capture, there's a checkbox labeled "Do not emit empty files when no events occur during the Capture time window."

Answer (score 0):

Why is this feature causing troubles to your logging system?

The Capture feature of Event Hub fires even if no events were received, based on the time interval configured; this is a way to let you know that the capturing is working properly.
As pointed out in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview)

> Once configured, Event Hubs Capture runs automatically when you send your first event, and continues running. To make it easier for your downstream processing to know that the process is working, Event Hubs writes empty files when there is no data. This process provides a predictable cadence and marker that can feed your batch processors.

If you also look at the Python example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-python#create-a-python-script-to-read-your-capture-files you can see that the code only considers non-empty files, with size greater than 508 bytes.